# How to use the AccountsService API with Python?

Tags: python, application-development

I'm writing an application for the Ubuntu app showdown and I try to read/write the user's profile picture using this

```
>>> from gi.repository import AccountsService, GLib
>>> current_user = GLib.get_user_name()
>>> user = AccountsService.UserManager.get_default().get_user(current_user)
>>> print user.get_icon_file()
None
>>> print user.get_user_name()
None
```

But apparently does not work. Is there another way to use AccountsService with Python?
I could not find more documentation about AccountsService and Python.

PS: to test this example you need to install `gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0` on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
$ sudo apt-get install gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0
```

Comment: Wow. There is NO documentation on `AccountsService`. No manpage, no docs from the .deb. Nothing. Hope someone who has intimate knowledge of it weighs in.

Comment: For people still smashing their heads against a wall, lazka has documentation for this now: https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/AccountsService-1.0/index.html

Answer (score 8):

After looking at the source to libaccountsservice you actually have to wait for the user to be loaded before accessing the user object.  This acheives the result:

```
from gi.repository import AccountsService, GLib

current_user = GLib.get_user_name()
user = AccountsService.UserManager.get_default().get_user(current_user)
def is_loaded_cb(user, param):
    print user.get_icon_file()
user.connect('notify::is-loaded', is_loaded_cb)

main_loop = GLib.MainLoop()
main_loop.run()
```

Alternatively, you can contact the accounts service directly and synchronously over D-Bus:

```
from gi.repository import GLib, Gio

current_user = GLib.get_user_name ()
bus = Gio.bus_get_sync (Gio.BusType.SYSTEM, None)
result = bus.call_sync ('org.freedesktop.Accounts',
                        '/org/freedesktop/Accounts',
                        'org.freedesktop.Accounts',
                        'FindUserByName',
                        GLib.Variant ('(s)', (current_user,)),
                        GLib.VariantType.new ('(o)'),
                        Gio.DBusCallFlags.NONE,
                        -1,
                        None)
(path,) = result.unpack ()

result = bus.call_sync ('org.freedesktop.Accounts',
                        path,
                        'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties',
                        'GetAll',
                        GLib.Variant ('(s)', ('org.freedesktop.Accounts.User',)),
                        GLib.VariantType.new ('(a{sv})'),
                        Gio.DBusCallFlags.NONE,
                        -1,
                        None)
(props,) = result.unpack ()
print props['IconFile']
print props['RealName']
```

If you want to set the icon file you need to call the appropriate method:

```
result = bus.call_sync ('org.freedesktop.Accounts',
                       path,
                       'org.freedesktop.Accounts.User',
                       'SetIconFile',
                       GLib.Variant ('(s)', ('/tmp/somefile.png',)),
                       GLib.VariantType.new ('()'),
                       Gio.DBusCallFlags.NONE,
                       -1,
                       None)
```

If you need to use any other methods, browse the D-Bus interface using D-Feet (in the software center).